# Order Properties while Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatables, json.net

I am serializing json string to array using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject like below

```
agreementnodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AgreementNode>>("[" + row["Txt"].ToString() + "]");
```

The below string will be deserialized to the AgreementNode class.

```
{ Text: "OWENS &amp; MINOR  INFANT - 2228548", Value: "File", ImageUrl: "AgreementMaintenance/agreement2.png", Folder: "",AgreementNbr:"2228",ExternalDescription:"248DST",Description :"OWENS",EffDate:"12 Dec 2015",ExpDate:"31 Mar 2015",ReleaseStatus:"" }
```

The properties in the resultant javascript array object corresponding to AgreementNode are ordered alphabetically. As I am binding this object directly to the JQuery Datatables where it has same columns with a change of order. I can change the order in DataTables to match the object but I dont want to do that as the order in the table is really important and I want to keep it same. Instead I want to change the order of the properties in the resultant javascript array to match the order in the Datatables.

I have tried decorating the properties like below to see if the order is effected. But the order is not effected.

```
 [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
 public string AgreementNbr { get; set; }
```

Can someone suggest me any other way where I can order the properties explicitly?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem? On a test class I made I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why is it so important for you C# class to have ordered properties? Anyway, you can order them however you want when manually creating the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties Order while Deserialization using JSON.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675470/properties-order-while-deserialization-using-json-net)

Comment: From what I have seen while trying to achieve the same is, you can set JsonProperty Order Attribute while serialising then it will be deserialized in the same order.