# Properties Order while Deserialization using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Deserialize the string to JSON Object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject like below:

```
 var str = "{ Value: \"File\",Text: \"OWENS &amp; MINOR  INFANT - 2228548\"}";
agreementnodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AgreementNode>>("[" + str + "]");
```

When the json is converted to an array the properties are alphabetically ordered. Example : Even though Value is first and Text is in the string the properties are displayed like below:

[image]

Even in the class declaration, I Value is Firs and Text is second. But when de-serializing, the properties are sorted alphabetically.

```
[JsonProperty(Order = 9)]
public string Value { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to retain the order of the properties in the resultant array like I want resultantarray[0] = Value and resultantarray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa9kS.png) = Text?

Comment: The order of the properties of an object in JS is completely arbitrary and cannot be reliably pre-defined. Is there a specific reason you need this? If it's due to the `Order` being specified on the `JsonProperty` attribute, you're best off defining a `Name` for the serialisation of the property instead of relying on the order they are provided to the ModelBinder.

Comment: I am binding the data directly to the JQuery Datatables where I have the properties in particular order. I dont want to mainipulate order of the objects client side and dont want to build a new array as it is rework.

Comment: My point is, why are they in a particular order? An objects properties cannot be relied on to be in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with json.net serializer. It's automatically ordered by alphabetical in quickwatch and watch windows. Check System.Web.HttpContext.SystemWebAssembly if you want. It's not a deserialized code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of properties are undefined according to the specification.  In spite of that the most current ECMAScript (JavaScript) specification requires an ordered format which also enables new cool applications like:
https://cyberphone.github.io/openkeystore/resources/docs/jcs.html#ECMAScript_Compatibility_Mode